# How can I initially hide the other language while browser asks for location?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, cookies

I'm using a script on my site to switch between chinese and english, It's a script i found in someones answer on stackoverflow.

This problem is, this script makes the users browser pop up a question "Blahblah.com wants to know your location. [Allow] [Block]" this is OK, but while it is showing that pop up, it is also displaying BOTH the languages divs and spans on the screen, so it is showing english div and right under it chinese div, How can I make it default to English language while the browser is asking for location?

the script is here:

```js
$(function () {
  ///// Language Switching (2 languages: English and Chinese). /////

  // Initially disable language switching button.
  $('#switch-lang').css({'pointer-events':'none',
   'cursor':'default'}).attr('disabled','disabled');
  

  function langButtonListen() {
    $('#switch-lang').on("click", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('[lang="zh"]').toggle();
      $('[lang="en"]').toggle();
      // Switch cookie stored language.
      if ($.cookie('lang') === 'en') {
        $.cookie('lang', 'zh', { expires: 7 });
      } else {
        $.cookie('lang', 'en', { expires: 7 });
      }
    });
    // Enable lang switching button.
    $('#switch-lang').css({'pointer-events':'auto',
     'cursor':'pointer'}).removeAttr('disabled');
  }

  // Check if language cookie already exists.
  if ($.cookie('lang')) {
    var lang = $.cookie('lang');
    if (lang === 'en') {
      $('[lang="zh"]').hide();
      langButtonListen();
    } else {
      $('[lang="en"]').hide();
      langButtonListen();
    }
  } else {
    // no cookie set, so detect language based on location.
    if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
      // geolocation is available
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        // accepted geolocation so figure out which country
        var lat = position.coords.latitude,
            lng = position.coords.longitude;
        $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+lat+','+lng+'&sensor=true', null, function (response) {
          var country = response.results[response.results.length-1].formatted_address;
          if (country ===  'Taiwan' || country === 'China') {
            $('[lang="en"]').hide();
            $.cookie('lang', 'zh', { expires: 7 });
            langButtonListen();
          } else {
            $('[lang="zh"]').hide();
            $.cookie('lang', 'en', { expires: 7 });
            langButtonListen();
          }
        }).fail(function (err) {
          console.log('error: '+err);
          $('[lang="zh"]').hide();
          $.cookie('lang', 'en', { expires: 7 });
          langButtonListen();
        });
      },
      function (error) {
        if (error.code == error.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
          // denied geolocation
          $('[lang="zh"]').hide();
          $.cookie('lang', 'en', { expires: 7 });
          langButtonListen();
        } else {
          console.log('Unknown error. Defaulting to English!');
          $('[lang="zh"]').hide();
          $.cookie('lang', 'en', { expires: 7 });
          langButtonListen();
        }
      });
    } else {
      // geolocation IS NOT available
      $('[lang="zh"]').hide();
      $.cookie('lang', 'en', { expires: 7 });
      langButtonListen();
    }
  }
});
```

I've tried various things involving this script and so far nothing is working. can anyone help to make it default to just show english while it is geolocating?

Comment: You could hide the other language divs initially (either with `$.hide()` or with `HTMLElement.style.display = "none"` or with CSS) and then `$.show()` the correct one once the location prompt is complete.

Comment: I tried $('[lang="zh"]').hide; before the script runs, i tried it in the body of the html right at the top too, i tried it on line 6 of my script too nothing worked, it still shows both langs while the browser awaits the action to allow geolocate

Comment: I figured it out:  I added,  $('[lang="zh"]').hide();  AFTER the line "if ("geolocation" in navigator) {"